USB hub with FE1.1S
OK, I put together a simple 2 port USB hub with the FE1.1S USB Hub IC, I wanted it to be as simple as possible and I based it on this circuit but I missed some connections that I didn't realise so my circuit doesn't work, this is my circuit

After researching many circuits it looks like I missed some pin to pin connections that I didn't think I needed based on reading the datasheet, apparently I was wrong.
So I've modified my circuit to include the connections I missed, I've left off a couple because the datasheet for this revision of the IC I'm using states NC on some of the pins.
I would be grateful of feedback on the new circuit to get some confidence that it'll work this time. (U3 is a wired connection to the USB plug for the host)
Also, there are no parallel capacitors with the crystal, some circuits have them and some don't could this be an issue?


This question is similar to: How can I add additional components and connections to make this USB hub functional?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

OK, thanks for pointing that out, I didn't find that post in my initial search, I have since taken the information from another post and managed to modify my current PCB to get it working so I now have confidence that my new design should work, I was looking for a third party review from people who've done it before, I'm sorry if this forum doesn't do that, please feel free to delete if you like.
